# Why does serialize() have the same effect as serializeArray() when setting post data for jQuery.ajax()?

Tags: jquery, forms, serialization

i have this jQuery-AJAX code below and a form:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('form').submit(function () {
        form_data = $(this).serializeArray();

        $.ajax({
            url: "/frontend_dev.php/coche1/update/id/1",
            type: "POST",
            data: form_data

            });
        });
        return false;

});
</script>
```

As you can see I'm using `serializeArray()` but when i use `serialize()` it also works the same..

Why in both cases works the same? What of them should i use?

Im using symfony as php framework. I can offer you more info if you need it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If an object/array gets passed (which [`.serializeArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) returns), it's serialized via [`$.param()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/).

If a string get passed (which [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) returns) it doesn't do anything further.

...so they have the same effect when passed as the `data` property.  [You can find the relevant check here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.4/src/ajax.js#L207):

```
    // convert data if not already a string
    if ( s.data && s.processData && typeof s.data !== "string" ) {
        s.data = jQuery.param( s.data, s.traditional );
    }
```

Which one should you use?  It *really* doesn't matter here, [`.serialize()` makes the same `$.param()` call](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.4/src/ajax.js#L89), so they do the exact same amount of work.  I personally use [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) because it's simply less to type.

Answer (score 5):

In this case, they're the same. But there is a big difference if you do not specify the type - serialize will do a GET and `serializeArray` will do a POST!

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that in CodeIgniter, the .serialize method can produce data that gets polluted by CodeIgniter's CSRF protection (CodeIgniter somehow adds semi-colons to the array keys), whereas the forms I've submitted with .serializeArray did not have this problem.

Also, if you're using complex POST names, e.g. name="some[a][data][structure]" where the places in the $_POST array changes and are not arbitrary, then using .serialize will probably be much easier because you can convert it back into a PHP data structure much more easily.