# previewing php/jquery form in fancybox, then submit or return to form

Tags: php, jquery, forms, fancybox, fancybox-2

I've got a basic html/php form, with jquery validation.  I want the user to be able to click a link that says "preview", have fancybox load up, and then I'll present a preview of the data, which means combining elements.  For instance, the user can choose the background of the iframe.  Here is the basics of my form -

```
    <form action="loggedin.php"  enctype="multipart/form-data" id="message_form" method="post">
    <h4>Who would you like to send a message to?</h4>
    <input type="text" size="35" id="recipient" name="recipient" value="Enter Name">
    <h4>Choose A Background: </h4>
    <input type="radio" value="plain" class="stationery_radio" name="stationery_radio" checked />
    <label for="plain">Plain</label>
     .....
```

And this is the info I want in my fancybox:

```
    <a class="fancybox" href="#preview_message">Click Here To Preview Your Form</a>
    <div id="preview_message" style="display:none;">
    <h2>To: <?php echo ($message_form['recipient']) ?></h2>
    .....
```

But I can't use the POST, as I haven't really submitted the form yet.  How can I sent the data to my fancybox where the user can look at it, and either submit the form or return to edit?  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I would do is to create another .php file (e.g. `preview.php`) where you can (pre)submit the form via ajax. This file would basically `echo` the `POST` values of your form fields like `$_POST['recipient']`, etc.

Additionally, within the same file (preview.php) you may have some links to either submit the actual form or close fancybox.

Here is an example of the preview.php file

```
<?php 
function check_input($data){
   // sanitize your inputs here
}
$field_01 = check_input($_POST['field_01']);
$field_02 = check_input($_POST['field_02']);
$field_03 = check_input($_POST['field_03']);
// ... etc
?>
<div style="width: 340px;">
  <h3>This is the preview of the form</h3><br />
  <p>Field 01 : <?php echo $field_01;?></p>
  <p>Field 02 : <?php echo $field_02;?></p>
  <p>Field 03 : <?php echo $field_03;?></p>
  <a class="submit" href="javascript:;">submit</a>
  <a class="closeFB" href="javascript:;">back to edit</a>
</div>
```

**notice** `style="width: 340px;"` so fancybox will know what size of box to display (`height` would be `auto`)

Then in your main page, add the *preview* button

```
<a class="preview" data-fancybox-type="ajax" href="preview.php">Preview</a>
```

**notice** the `data-fancybox-type="ajax"` attribute, which tells fancybox the `type` of content.

Then the script to submit (preview) the form via ajax :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  $('.preview').on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      cache: false,
      url: this.href, // our preview file (preview.php)
      data: $("#message_form").serializeArray(), // all the fields in your form (use the form's ID)
      success: function (data) {
        // show in fancybox the returned data
        $.fancybox(data,{
          modal : true, // optional (no close button, etc. see docs.)
          afterShow: function(){
            // bind click to "submit" and "close" buttons inside preview.php
            $(".submit, .closeFB").on("click", function(event){
              if( $(event.target).is(".submit") ){
                $("#message_form").submit(); // submit the actual form
              }
              $.fancybox.close(); //close fancybox in any case
            }); // on click
          } // afterShow
        }); // fancybox
      } // success
    }); // ajax
  }); // on click
}); // ready
```

Of course, the DEMO at http://www.picssel.com/playground/jquery/postPreview_05Jun13.html.

**NOTES**:

- this is for fancybox v2.1.4+
- `.on()` requires jQuery v1.7+

Comment: Worked like a charm - thank you so much!  You saved me hours of work as I was headed in the wrong direction!

Comment: One more question.... when I select "Back to Edit" my form is wiped out, when I really want to keep what's in the form already.  Also, submit doesn't actually submit the form - it just takes me back to my original form!

Comment: @KathyLyons : in my demo, when you press "back to edit" the form retains the edited values that you can change and re-preview oever and over again... and submit it does actually submit the form. I wonder what you are doing differently.

Comment: I actually cut and pasted your code - I have a sample here:
[link](https://untilnexttime.org/loggedin.php)[/link].  I'll retry everything again.

Comment: @KathyL your "back to edit" button has class "submit" so, of course the form is submitted

Comment: Changed my butons to exactly what you have above:
        <a class="submit btn login-submit"  href="">Submit</a>
       <a class="closeFB btn" href="">Back to Edit</a>

Comment: why you don't try validating your document http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=https://untilnexttime.org/loggedin.php and fixing the existing errors so you can narrow down the issue? .... the `<html>` opening tag is misplaced for instance.

Comment: Good idea.  Just did that.  Behavior is still the same, no matter what I choose.  "Back to edit" wipes my form and returns me to the blank form, and "Submit" does the same thing, and does not submit the data to the db. Frustrating.

Comment: More data... In my sendmessage.class.php, I check to see if the POST is empty - it is.  In Firebug I see the POST values and they are populated with the correct values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery, to get the values, and put them into the fancy box...

A little like this...not quite, but you get the idea...

```
 $('#preview_button').click(function(){

var msg = $('#recipient').val();
var bg = $('input:radio[name=stationary_radio]:checked').val();

$('h2#recipient').html(msg);
//and whatever you wanna do with the value of the bg
//probably apply some CSS on the fly to change the preview background?
$('#fancybox').show();
```

});

The fancybox show() is likely wrong, never used fancybox, so I dont know, but Im just using a generic, 'hidden div' show.  I assume fancybox has its own API that is different, so just substitute...