# how to load an ajax content dynamically to fancybox iframe

Tags: jquery, ajax, iframe, fancybox-2

I want to show preview of a form on clicking of preview button, so i'm just firing an ajax call (with post request) here to show the data in the fancybox. here is my code

```
$('#preview').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.fancybox.showLoading();
    $.post($(this).attr('href'), $('form').serialize(), function(res) {
        $.fancybox(res, {
            beforeShow : function() {
                // do some thing
            }
        });
    });
})
```

it is working fine, but need to show the ajax response in fancybox of type **iframe** in order to show it in proper design.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `res` the response you get back?

Comment: `res` is the response coming from ajax

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/a/14343547/1055987 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/16956120/1055987

Comment: possible duplicate of [Post preview - Passing data with AJAX and Fancybox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14316054/post-preview-passing-data-with-ajax-and-fancybox)

Comment: yes it is. but i need to open the response in fancybox of type iframe instead of ajax @JFK .

Comment: please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4614850/jquery-add-iframe-with-content my question is exactly similar to this one @JFK.