# How to pass form data to fancybox?

Tags: forms, iframe, fancybox, submit

Is it possible to pass this input data to a fancybox iframe? And if it is, then how? I need to pass this id variable to the fancybox so I can echo that ID in fancybox. Here's the code. Thanks in advance,

```
<form action="info.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="id" class="invisible" value="' . $row["id"] . '">
    <button type="submit" id="check">Result</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14316054/post-preview-passing-data-with-ajax-and-fancybox and let me know if that answers your question.

Comment: Thanks! It did the job. The ID is passed but there some problems left. Now if i click on the result button it opens an fancybox iframe with the id in there, but it displays the last id of the database table, not the one i have selected. And the fancybox doesn't open the second time when I close the first one.