# AJAX Form Submission - Selecting all inputs except unchecked checkboxes

Tags: jquery, forms

I am creating a small CRM that has many AJAX-powered forms. I am trying to establish the best neutral data selection tool for getting all data for a form.

One issue I am having is that checkboxes always come up as "on" when doing `$('#checkbox').val()`. My goal is to write 1 selection that will get all items that have data within them. My current selection statement is quite bare:

```
$('input, select, textarea').each( function() {
    // do stuff with the data, and create a dataString
}
```

I have tried using `:not()`, but what I really want to do is get ALL input tags that are NOT unchecked checkboxes. Is there some nested selector I can use? I know `:checked` is always available, but I was trying to keep it as non-specific as possible. I know i could do:

```
$('input[type=text], input:checked, type[type=hidden] .... ')
```

And so on, but I'm looking to keep it nice and short (if possible!)

Thanks guys!

Comment: Do you want the query to return radio buttons (unchecked or checked)?

Comment: the idea is to eventually include radio buttons as well (only selected), but the forms I have created so far only feature the items mentioned above. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `$('form#myForm').serializeArray()`, which ignores unchecked boxes. As does `$('form#myForm').serialize()`.

Comment: Thank you! What is the difference between `serializeArray()` and `serialize()`? jQuery vs native? any speed differences?

Comment: Found the answer - `serialize()` returns a string, it seems! Very cool. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10430502/whats-the-difference-between-serialize-and-serializearray