# .serialize does not pass parameters correctly

Tags: php, jquery

I am sending a serialized form with $.post to a Controller PHP:

```
$.post('/Controller.php',
    {
        action: 'register',
      data: $('#regForm').serialize()                       
    },
  function(msg){

        if(parseInt(msg.status)==1)
        {
            window.location=msg.txt;
        }
        else if(parseInt(msg.status)==0)
        {
            error(1,msg.txt);
        }

        hideshow('loading',0);
    }, 
    "json"      
);
```

I would now expect to be able to access the Form fields by $_POST['fieldname']
 but INSTEAD
I have a Get like parameter string in $_POST['data'] -.- What do I do wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's sending the data just as you told it to.  `.serialize()` creates a "query string", which you added into `$_POST['data']`.

Instead of what you have, try this:

```
var formData = $('#regForm').serialize();
var extraFields = {action: 'register'};

$.post('/Controller.php', $.param(extraFields)+'&'+formData, function(msg){
    if(parseInt(msg.status)==1)
    {
        window.location=msg.txt;
    }
    else if(parseInt(msg.status)==0)
    {
        error(1,msg.txt);
    }

    hideshow('loading',0);
}, 'json');
```

Now you should be able to get `$_POST['action']` and `$_POST['fieldname']`.

Comment: This does exactly what I need. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

the $.post format is like this:

```
jQuery.post( url [, data ] [, success(data, textStatus, jqXHR) ] [, dataType ] )
```

so your first parameter is url correct, the second is data. that is why you are getting $_POST['data'] and $_POST['action'] as post parameters, since indeed you send two url parameters 'action' and 'data'. you could do like this and send the form directly as data:

```
$.post('/Controller.php',
       $('#regForm').serialize(),
  function(msg){

        if(parseInt(msg.status)==1)
        {
            window.location=msg.txt;
        }
        else if(parseInt(msg.status)==0)
        {
            error(1,msg.txt);
        }

        hideshow('loading',0);
    }, 
    "json"      
);
```

then you'll get what you ask for, $_POST['fieldname']

Comment: I assume he needed the `$_POST['action']` value too.

Comment: in that case your answer is more complete.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your input fields in your form have the `name` attribute assigned otherwise jQuery will not send the data correctly.

The other option is to use `serializeArray`. The difference between the two [has been discussed here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10430502/whats-the-difference-between-serialize-and-serializearray)

```
$.post('/Controller.php',
    {
        action: 'register',
      data: $('#regForm').serializeArray()                       
    },
  function(msg){
        if(parseInt(msg.status)==1)
        {
            window.location=msg.txt;
        }
        else if(parseInt(msg.status)==0)
        {
            error(1,msg.txt);
        }

        hideshow('loading',0);
    }      
)
```

Comment: This won't work quite as you expect it to.  In PHP, you will get `$_POST['data'][0]['name']` and `$_POST['data'][0]['value']`.  You'd probably want to do something like: `var data = $('#regForm').serializeArray();  data.push({name:'action',value:'register'});  $.post('/Controller.php', data, function(){});`.