# Can't retrieve jQuery serialized form data with PHP $_POST[] variable

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

Using Ajax jQuery function `$.post()`, I'm sending jQuery `serialized()` form data to a PHP function which successfully receives it in `$_POST[]` yet individual `$_POST['form_field']` variables are empty.

In my PHP function, `print_r($_POST)` successfully displays the form data:

```
Array ( [action] => send_message [data] => modal_name=olivier&modal_email=olivier%40hotmail.com&modal_message=Hello+world )
```

Yet `$_POST['modal_name']`, `$_POST['modal_email']` and `$_POST['modal_message']`
are empty. Why?

HTML:

```
<form id='contact'>
  <input type='text' name='modal_name' id='modal_name' />
  <input type='email' name='modal_email' id='modal_email' />
  <textarea name='modal_message' id='modal_message'></textarea>
</form>
```

JS:

```
$('#contact').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (modal_name && modal_email && modal_message) {
    var data = {
      action: 'send_message',
      data: $(this).serialize()
    };
    $.post(WPaAjax.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
      $('.modal').append(response);
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: As you can see in `$_POST`, your `data` key contains a serialized string. So you can either parse that or don't serialize twice and send the serialized form directly: `var data = $(this).serialize()`;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `$(this).serializeArray()` instead of `$(this).serialize()`

Reference:- https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/

The difference between both:-https://stackoverflow.com/a/10430571/4248328

***You need to do like below:-***

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id='contact'>
  <input type='text' name='modal_name' id='modal_name' />
  <input type='email' name='modal_email' id='modal_email' />
  <textarea name='modal_message' id='modal_message'></textarea>
  <input type="submit" value = "submit">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#contact').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (modal_name && modal_email && modal_message) {
     var data = $(this).serializeArray();
     data.push({name: 'action', value: 'send_message'});
     $.post('query.php', data, function(response) {
      $('.modal').append(response);
    });
  }
});
</script>
```

And in php:-

```
<?php

if(!empty($_POST)){
    echo "<pre/>";print_r($_POST);
}
?>
```

It will output like this:-

```
<pre/>Array
(
    [modal_name] => sdsadsa
    [modal_email] => a@gmail.com
    [modal_message] => sadada
    [action] => send_message
)
```

***Note:- if you want to use `serialize()`only then do like below:-***

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#contact').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (modal_name && modal_email && modal_message) {
     var data = $(this).serialize()+ '&action=send_message';
     $.post('query.php', data, function(response) {
      $('.modal').append(response);
    });
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks but $_POST['modal_name'] is still empty.

Comment: Looks like the double serializing messed everything up, works now thanks!

Comment: @drake035   glad to help you:):)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `$_POST['data']['modal_name']`, `$_POST['data']['modal_email']` and `$_POST['data']['modal_message']` instead. Also use `$.serializeArray()` from jQuery.

The reason is that you send form data as param called `data`.

Comment: Using serializeArray() now, $_POST['data']['modal_name'] is empty and $_POST['modal_name'] as well.