# How to get data in php from $.post into $variable?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, .post

I have found a lot of answers to this matter, but did not found working solution for my form posting with $.post to a php file which stores data into a csv file.

The formData gets serialized in another function which stores the data in a const for storing localy. The actually $.post gets done in this part of code.

jQuery code:

```
function submit(formData) {

   function passVal(){

       $.post(
           "post.php",
           formData,
           function(formData,status,xhr){

           }
       );

    return false;

   }
    passVal();


}
```

PHP Code:

```
$obj = $_POST;
$retailer = $obj['retailer'];

$question1  = $obj['question1'];
$offline = $obj['offline'];
$question2_1 = $obj['question2_1'];
$question2_2 = $obj['question2_2'];
$question2_3 = $obj['question2_3'];
$question3 = $obj['question3'];
$timestamp = $formdata['timestamp'];

$old_file = fopen('/output/results.csv', 'a');


$list = array
(
    $retailer . ';' . $question1  . ';' . $question2_1  . ';' . $question2_2  . ';' . $question2_3  . ';' . $question3 . ';' . $offline . ';' .$timestamp


);
fputcsv($old_file, $list);

fclose($old_file);
```

Is there a working solution?
These answers: 
[Can't retrieve jQuery serialized form data with PHP $_POST[] variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42623577/cant-retrieve-jquery-serialized-form-data-with-php-post-variable)
Do not work for me.

I wanted to get the data into the different $vars in php?

Comment: I don't understand.. what is your exact problem with this code now? Do you get any error? Whats happening?

Comment: The vars do not get filled.... they are empty

Comment: I see, have you investigated the ajax call in the browser dev tools network tab? Are these fields: 'question1' 'offline' etc. actually sent? Have you tried `var_dump($_POST);`?

Comment: yes they are... and if I store them in a log file... the entire string is there

Comment: ?? "if I store them in a log file"? How can they be empty if you can store them in a log file

Comment: the entire string is stored in log file... but parts of the string I cannot seperate

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189094/discussion-between-xatenev-and-sjoerd).

Comment: I recommend posting and accepting your own answer, based on your findings in chat.

Answer (score 0):

With help from Xatenev, I found the next solution:

```
$obj = $_POST['data'];
parse_str($obj, $output);
$question1 = $output['question1'];
```

$obj = $_POST['data'] will give you a string: question1=Yes&question2=No

parse_str() will parse string into variables. And now it can be used in my php file
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

tnx community for the quick help&response!