# Json serialize is not serialize some html data using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have some dynamic form elements that should get value from some calculation based on the text fields. While serializing the calculated fields are not serialized.

The below code represents the exact scenario

Scenario:1
while i click add button it will create the new entry but the value is (cgst_val) not placed on the text box

Scenario:2
Json serialize is not take the value which calculated using the tax_val and tax_per

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#add").click(function() {
    var $clone = $('#container .group:first').clone();
    $clone.find('input').val('');
    $clone.find('select').val('2');
    $clone.append('<a href="#" class="remove">X</a>');
    $clone.appendTo('#container');
  });
  $("#container").on('click', '.remove', function() {
    $(this).parent('.group').remove();
  });
  $('#container').on('input, change', ".P_tax_per", ".P_state", function() {
    var $group = $(this).closest('.group');
    var num1 = parseInt($group.find(".P_tax_val").val(), 10) || 0;
    var num2 = parseInt($group.find(".P_tax_per").val(), 10) || 0;
    var num3 = num1 / num2 * 100;
    $group.find(".P_cgst_val").attr('value', num3);
  });
});


$("form").submit(function() {
  var result = {};
  $.each($('form').serializeArray(), function() {
    result[this.name] = this.value;
  });
  var jsonData1 = {
    tax_val: result.tax_val,
    tax_per: result.tax_per,
    cgst_val: result.cgst_val
  };
  var myJSON = JSON.stringify(jsonData1);
  alert(myJSON);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="button" id="add" value="ADD" />
  <div id="container">
    <div class="group">
      <input type="text" name="tax_val" class="P_tax_val" />
      <select name="tax_per" class="P_tax_per">
        <option disabled selected value>GST %</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="12">12</option>
      </select>
      <input type="text" name="cgst_val" class="P_cgst_val" size="3" placeholder="cs" value="" disabled />
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" name="SUBMIT" />
</form>
```

Comment: `result[this.name] = this.value;` is overwritten each time because of the same name. Instead just do `myJSON = JSON.stringiFy($('form').serialize())`

Comment: If you're only going to pull three values from the form, just pull the three values from the fields directly. I wouldn't even bother with `serialize`...

Comment: @HereticMonkey They add a row per click so unknown number of rows

Comment: @mplungjan The existing code only ever pulls three values. It's not clear, to me, whether that's intended behavior or not; they could be saving incrementally for all I know...

Comment: @HereticMonkey very clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need the each statement to serialize all fields.
Looking at your code you could do something like this:

```
$("form").submit(function() {
  var myJSON = JSON.stringify($('form').serializeArray());
  alert(myJSON);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`result[this.name] = this.value;` is overwritten each time because of the same name.

Instead just do this (and remember the preventDefault if you need to ajax

Also you need to NOT have disabled if you want to pass a field. I made the cs field grey and readonly

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#add").click(function() {
    var $clone = $('#container .group:first').clone();
    $clone.find('input').val('');
    $clone.find('select').val('2');
    $clone.append('<a href="#" class="remove">X</a>');
    $clone.appendTo('#container');
  });
  $("#container").on('click', '.remove', function() {
    $(this).parent('.group').remove();
  });
  $('#container').on('input, change', ".P_tax_per, .P_state", function() {
    var $group = $(this).closest('.group');
    var num1 = parseInt($group.find(".P_tax_val").val(), 10) || 0;
    var num2 = parseInt($group.find(".P_tax_per").val(), 10) || 0;
    var num3 = num1 / num2 * 100;
    $group.find(".P_cgst_val").val(num3);
  });
});


$("form").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var myString= JSON.stringify($("form").serialize());
  alert(myString);
});
```

```css
.P_cgst_val { background-color:#EBEBE4 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="button" id="add" value="ADD" />
  <div id="container">
    <div class="group">
      <input type="text" name="tax_val" class="P_tax_val" />
      <select name="tax_per" class="P_tax_per">
        <option disabled selected value>GST %</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="12">12</option>
      </select>
      <input type="text" name="cgst_val" class="P_cgst_val" size="3" placeholder="cs" value="" readonly />
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" name="SUBMIT" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply in this case the second dynamic element is not get value into cgst_val text box

Comment: because it is disabled

Comment: @mplugjan Thanks for your reply it works fine but i need serializeArray(); with input name and value

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10430502/whats-the-difference-between-serialize-and-serializearray